# What is setting $VERSION good for?

Tags: perl

Lot's of ways to set your modules `$VERSION` in perl, some even have advantages. What I don't know is why we do it? I mean the META.yml has a version... which is what `cpan` uses? so why do we set it in the module? what's the point?

Comment: Actually, cpan(1) uses the version from the PAUSE index files. There's no way for it to know what's in META.yml before downloading and unpacking the dist.

Comment: @briandfoy The META.yml files are available separate from the tarball as `authors/id/A/AU/AUTHOR/Dist-Name-X.Y.meta`, but you need to know the author, distribution and version already to get it so there's a clear chicken/egg problem.

Comment: I know they are available *after* PAUSE indexes it and puts it in the directory that CPAN will mirror. Before PAUSE does that, none of the files in the distro are available to the public.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So you can say

```
use Module::Name 4.5.6;
```

And the code will fail if you don't have at least version 4.5.6 of Module::Name installed.

It is also helpful when you need to know what version is installed, you can just say:

```
perl -MScalar::Util=99999999999999
```

This is roughly equivalent to

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Scalar::Util 99999999999999;
```

It will fail (becuase `Scalar::Util` is nowhere near version 99999999999999) and tell you the version number.  In my case it says:

```
Scalar::Util version v.Inf required--this is only version 1.22 at
/Users/cowens/apps/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.12.1/lib/5.12.1/Exporter/Heavy.pm
line 120.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

Comment: I like the one-liner trick. I beats having to type the full module name twice: `perl -MScalar::Util -e "print $Scalar::Util::VERSION"`

Comment: @toolic You can save yourself one character when you do that way by using the `VERSION` method, rather than the `$VERSION` scalar: `perl -MScalar::Util -E "say Scalar::Util->VERSION"`, but yeah, having to repeat yourself sucks.

Comment: have a look at `pmvers` from the pmtools package if you want to know which version of a package is installed

Comment: @toolic, @Chas: you should do `-m` rather than `-M`, to avoid importing methods.

Comment: @plusplus Will `pmtools` be installed on every machine I got to?  No?  Thanks, but I will stick with the simple command that works everywhere.

Comment: @Ether I guess it saves you from hitting shift, but it doesn't really do anything here.

Answer (score 5):

From [perlmodlib: Guidelines for Module Creation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html#Guidelines-for-Module-Creation):

> To be fully compatible with the
>   Exporter and MakeMaker modules you
>   should store your module's version
>   number in a non-my package variable
>   called $VERSION.

To supplement the Answers given by others, here is the link to [use MODULE VERSION](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html)

Answer (score 3):

So if your module is widely used and actively maintained, people can reference the version easily in their code to activate/deactivate their code depending on what version they use. Just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

`$VERSION` is available in code. For example, a user of your module can write

```
use YourModule 2.3;
```

to ensure that a minimum version of YourModule is available. This is important for API changes, bug fixes, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a little off topic, but since perl 5.12 you can set your modules VERSION simply by doing

```
package Foo::Bar 1.23;
```

See [perl 5.12 changes](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.0/pod/perl5120delta.pod#Core_Enhancements).

The version number must adhere to the "strict" format though, see [$version::STRICT](http://p3rl.org/version::Internals#$version::STRICT) in version::Internals.

Comment: Thanks, because my reputations is so low the spam prevention kicks in and denies me more than 1 link pr. post.

Comment: yeah I was aware of that ;) it's why I said there are many ways to define $VERSION. I can think of no less than 4. But I won't start using that syntax until 5.14.1 (is available out of testing in Arch ) at the earliest.