# How should I control versions of my Perl Moose objects?

Tags: perl, versioning, moose

I'm a `Moose` newbie and I wonder if the common

```
our $VERSION = "0.001";
$VERSION = eval $VERSION;
```

should also be used in Moose packages, or `Moose` has some alternative way for version control. Couldn't find a reference in `Moose` docs.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639403/perl-version-string-why-use-eval-expr and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632135/what-is-setting-version-good-for. But in general, no there is no different/special way of handling package versions in Moose; the normal conventions apply.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As with all perl packages, it is usually a good idea to have a `$VERSION` defined in them. This allows other things to properly depend on the version of them with all the features they need, either by declaring a dependency in their `Makefile.PL` or equivalent, or directly when loading the module using `use SomeModule 1.23;`.

The `eval` construct you're showing is a kludge. There is a distinction between regular releases of a module, and development releases. Traditionally that has been indicated by a `$VERSION` with an underscore in it. That means something like `0.001` would be a normal, stable release, while something like `0.001_01` would be a development release.

The `eval` is used to get rid of that underscore at runtime, while still preserving it in the version string that the various tools, including PAUSE, the Perl Authors Upload SErver, extract. This is to avoid warnings such as `0.001_01 is not numeric in ...`.

You'll find that idiom in lots of code. Luckily, there's a good alternative to it. Instead of indicating the development vs. non-development status in the version number of individual modules, you can also do that in the release tarball that you might upload to CPAN by using the `-TRIAL` flag.

Instead of uploading your distribution as `My-Distribution-0.001.tar.gz`, you can rename it to `My-Distribution-0.001-TRIAL.tar.gz`. The CPAN tools will pick that up and treat it as a development release accordingly. Note that `-TRIAL` is not part of the `$VERSION`, only of the tarball name. Therefore the `eval` kludge becomes unnecessary.

Also note that there are alternative ways to declare a package's `$VERSION`. As of perl 5.12.0, you are able to declare it right with in the package declaration:

```
package My::Package 0.001;
```

However, none of this is specific to `Moose` in any way.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the detailed answer and the update re. perl 5.12.0.

Comment: No, you don't. `package NAME VERSION;` was a syntax error in earlier perls, so this feature doesn't need to be enabled explicitly. You can still do it tho, and get all the other things `use 5.012` does for you for free, like, for example, enabling the `strict` pragma.